# change SVG color by button click not work for all SVG image | jquery

Tags: jquery, svg

My code is for changing SVG color with a button. The code is working well for one SVG, but not for the all others.

```html
<text>First SVG not work</text>
<button type="button" id="Change_Blue_Circle">Change color</button>
<div id="my-div"></div>
```

```js
new Vivus('my-div', {
  duration: 200,
  file: 'http://www.stirox.com/R/uploads/s.svg'
}, function() {
  alert(1);
});

$(document).on('click', '#Change_Blue_Circle', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $("#my-div svg:first path[fill='#42352c']").each(function(index) {
    $(this).css('fill', 'yellow');
  });
});
```

[check my site](http://www.stirox.com/R/)

Comment: When you say "code is working well for one SVG, but not for the all others" are there others that are not working that's not in your code? Please show all of your code.

Comment: check my site , there is 2 SVG one above one bottem , the above one not work

Comment: One SVG has fills as attributes so the CSS matches something, the other doesn't so the CSS matches nothing and therefore does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your JS code for button clicks with below one:

**JS Code**:

```
function rgb2hex(rgb){
    rgb = rgb.match(/^rgba?[\s+]?\([\s+]?(\d+)[\s+]?,[\s+]?(\d+)[\s+]?,[\s+]?(\d+)[\s+]?/i);
    return (rgb && rgb.length === 4) ? "#" + ("0" + parseInt(rgb[1],10).toString(16)).slice(-2) + ("0" + parseInt(rgb[2],10).toString(16)).slice(-2) + ("0" + parseInt(rgb[3],10).toString(16)).slice(-2) : '';
}

$(document).on('click','#Change_Blue_Circle',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#my-div svg:first path").each(function(index) {
        var fillCSSVal = '', attrFillVal = '', comparingColorValue = '#42352c';
        if( typeof $(this).css("fill") != 'undefined' ) {
            fillCSSVal = rgb2hex($(this).css("fill")).toString().toLowerCase();
        }
        if( typeof $(this).attr('fill') != 'undefined' ) {
            attrFillVal = $(this).attr('fill').toString().toLowerCase();
        }

        if( fillCSSVal == comparingColorValue || attrFillVal == comparingColorValue ) {
            $(this).css('fill', 'yellow');
        }
    });
});

$(document).on('click','#Change_Green_Circle',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#my-div2 svg:first path").each(function(index) {
        var fillCSSVal = '', attrFillVal = '', comparingColorValue = '#9cca15';
        if( typeof $(this).css("fill") != 'undefined' ) {
            fillCSSVal = rgb2hex($(this).css("fill")).toString().toLowerCase();
        }
        if( typeof $(this).attr('fill') != 'undefined' ) {
            attrFillVal = $(this).attr('fill').toString().toLowerCase();
        }

        if( fillCSSVal == comparingColorValue || attrFillVal == comparingColorValue ) {
            $(this).css('fill', 'red');
        }
    });
});
```

script will check whether SVG with path elements have either direct attribute as "fill" or have a css with "fill" property as required color value.

Function rgb2hex will give hexadecimal color value from rgb values, it's reference taken from JS Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/xcqpF/1/light/

**E.G. rgb(255, 255, 255) will be returned as #fffff**